# Comma with Participle Clause

Tags: commas, participles

Could someone please provide clarification regarding the comma in the sentence below? I thought that participle clauses did *not* require a comma unless they began the sentence (e.g. "Despite having read the article several times, the student was unable to express the author's main point").

> The student was unable to express the author's main point, despite having read the article several times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the participle clause relates to the last item in the main clause, no comma is required. In the following sentence, for example, the participle clause applies to "dog".

> He watched the **dog** *wagging its tail*

If the participle clause refers to something earlier in the sentence, a comma is required. In this sentence, for example, the participle clause relates to "the student".

> **The student** was unable to understand the author's main point, *finding the whole article virtually unintelligible*.

See [here](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm) for more information.

In your sentence, **despite** is a preposition, so it's actually a prepositional phrase. Check out [rule 8](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/607/), which states that a comma is required if a phrase *of any kind* refers back to the beginning or middle of the sentence. Your example is therefore correctly punctuated, because the prepositional phrase refers back to **the student**.

> **The student** was unable to express the author's main point, *despite having read the article several times*.

Comment: How about this sentence? _The student was unable to express the author's main point, despite the main point being quite straightforward._ Here, since the PP refers back to the end of the main clause, should the comma be removed or at least optional?

Comment: @JK2: I agree that the comma should be optional, butit is quite a long prepositional phrase and I think the comma makes it more understandable. You could actually shorten the PP by making it "despite its being quite straighforward".